# Moderator Pro Tempore Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators *Pro Tempore***](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Chenmunka] [image: LaceySnr] [image: wizzwizz4]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators *Pro Tempore*. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 11):

I would just like to say that I will try to live up to the trust now placed in me.

The purpose of a moderator is to enact the wishes of the community, so I look forward to seeing continued healthy discussions on the meta site.

I'll try to be available in the chat room, whatever it winds up [being called](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/what-should-we-name-our-chatroom), as much as possible.  There is a remarkable dearth of activity there at the moment.

Here's to the successful graduation of Retrocomputing.